# jQuery Datatables use function as ajax data source instead of path or url

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

How do you use functions as a data source for ajax with datatables? I'm using it in an electron application with a built in database where i'm calling a function, writing the results to a data.json file, and then using the file as the source:

```
populateData(); //gets data from db and writes output to data.json

let table = $('#accTransaction').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      select: {
        style: 'single'
      },
      ajax: '../data.json',
      ...
```

Instead, it would be more efficient if I could call the db function directly like this but it's not working....not valid url.

```
let table = $('#accTransaction').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      select: {
        style: 'single'
      },
      ajax: getData(),
      ...
```

I realize I can make the source 'data: newData,' but then I loose the ablility to call `table.ajax.reload`

```
setInterval( function () {
  table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
  console.log('reloading..')
}, 3000 );
```

How do you use functions as a data source for ajax with datatables instead of url's or file paths?

Comment: Are you sure you are using [jquery datatables](https://datatables.net/)? If not - which plugin do you use?

Comment: Maybe you can use function in `data` parameter in `ajax` option!

Comment: @Dekel, you can checkout the download builder at https://datatables.net/download/ to see lots of plugins. The ajax: is built in. See here https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know if it is any worth, but you could wrap the ajax call itself into a function, and in that function reinitialise the table using the `destroy` flag. From the demo below :

```js
function reload(url) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done(function(json) {
     console.log(json) //check the reponse
     return $('#example').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data : json.data,
        columns: [
           { data: 'name', title: 'Name' },
           { data: 'position', title: 'Position' }
        ]
     })
  })
}
```

Now you can refresh the dataTable simply by

```js
reload('url/to/json')
```

Where you can change the url to anything, just remember to change the `columns` definition properly ( or build it dynamically). It could be done using a interval :

```js
setInterval(function() {
   reload('https://api.myjson.com/bins/38p4r')
}, 1000)
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zefL681c/**

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the option. The issue is I'm using `table.ajax.relaod()` so I don't have to rebuild the table and loose paging when data is updated https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() . So I was trying to find a way to provide a non ajax function ( `ajax: getData()` ) that returns json, instead of providing a url to a file that contains json. I'm only building a file (`data.json`) so i can use the ajax table reload feature and keep the benefits that come with it.

Comment: @jtlindsey, Yes, I understand that. The problem is that the ajax attribute not support promises. If it did it would be easy, but now we have a scenario where dataTables not is waiting for a data-getter method to finish before it is trying to access data, so another approach is necessary. You do not have to loose paging or sorting settings, in fact I believe a simple `stateSave: true` would solve that issue, it will save the settings on destroy and reload when it is reinitialised.